# open new page based on combobox choice and click button

Tags: php, html, combobox

i have combobox code like this

```
<form action="plot.php" method="POST">
    <select name="variabel">
        <option value="no2">NO2</option>
        <option value="so2">SO2</option>
        <option value="ozone">ozone</option>
        <option value="aerosol">aerosol</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="plot" style="width:500px;height:48px">
```

and in file named "plot.php" like this

```
<?php
  $variabel = $_POST['variabel'];

  if ($variabel = "no2") {
    header("location:maps_no2.php");
  } else if ($variabel = "so2") {
    header("location:maps_so2.php");
  } else if ($variabel = "ozone") {
    header("location:maps_ozone.php");
  } else {
    header("location:maps_aerosol.php");
  }
?>
```

all i want is when i pick one of the item in my combobox, it will be the parameter for the other page to open after i click "plot" button.
for the example, when i pick NO2, maps_no2.php will show. when i try that code above, it just work on the first condition, although i pick so2. how can i solve this? anyone?? please.

Comment: you're doing assignments instead of comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
<?php
 if $variabel = $_POST['variabel'];
```

Should be

```
<?php
  if $variabel == $_POST['variabel'];
```

If you just use the single =, it SETS the variable to that value.  Then it will always be true.

Comment: thanks for answer but it still the same. it just want go to the first condition :(

Comment: I fixed my answer, as I forgot the IF part.  Which is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare, in your statements you are assigning instead:

```
<?php
  $variabel = $_POST['variabel'];

  if ($variabel == "no2") {
  header("location:maps_no2.php");
  }
  else if ($variabel == "so2")
  {
  header("location:maps_so2.php");
  }
  else if ($variabel == "ozone")
  {
  header("location:maps_ozone.php");
  }
  else 
  {
  header("location:maps_aerosol.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: best to also add `exit;` after each header ;-) I think the OP isn't aware of that.

Comment: oh yes! thanks it works :)

Comment: okay fred thanks for tell me that :)

Comment: @nikenriyanti you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` for comparisons

```
<?php
  $variabel = $_POST['variabel'];

  if ($variabel == "no2") {
    header("location:maps_no2.php");
  } else if ($variabel == "so2") {
    header("location:maps_so2.php");
  } else if ($variabel == "ozone") {
    header("location:maps_ozone.php");
  } else {
    header("location:maps_aerosol.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: oh yes! thanks it works :)